# how to sum and get max value in array object with group by id javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var myArray = [
  {"Emiten_ID":'SMBR',"Lot":500,"Price":2500},     
  {"Emiten_ID":'SMBR',"Lot":300,"Price":2200},     
  {"Emiten_ID":'ELSA',"Lot":500,"Price":1000},
  {"Emiten_ID":'SMBR',"Lot":100,"Price":3000},     
  {"Emiten_ID":'BI',"Lot":300,"Price":500},     
  {"Emiten_ID":'AAI',"Lot":200,"Price":1300},
  {"Emiten_ID":'BTB',"Lot":700,"Price":2900},     
  {"Emiten_ID":'BI',"Lot":150,"Price":200},     
  {"Emiten_ID":'AAI',"Lot":200,"Price":600},
];
```

i want result like this, where i get sum from lot and max value from price

```
var Result= [
  {"Emiten_ID":'ELSA',"Lot":500,"Price":1000},
  {"Emiten_ID":'SMBR',"Lot":900,"Price":3000},     
  {"Emiten_ID":'BI',"Lot":450,"Price":500},     
  {"Emiten_ID":'BTB',"Lot":700,"Price":2900},     
  {"Emiten_ID":'AAI',"Lot":400,"Price":1300},
];
```

Comment: I don't see any JavaScript (other than the problem and a desired result), what have you tried with JavaScript? Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and an object as hash table and group it by `Emiten_ID`.

```js
var myArray = [{ "Emiten_ID": 'SMBR', "Lot": 500, "Price": 2500 }, { "Emiten_ID": 'SMBR', "Lot": 300, "Price": 2200 }, { "Emiten_ID": 'ELSA', "Lot": 500, "Price": 1000 }, { "Emiten_ID": 'SMBR', "Lot": 100, "Price": 3000 }, { "Emiten_ID": 'BI', "Lot": 300, "Price": 500 }, { "Emiten_ID": 'AAI', "Lot": 200, "Price": 1300 }, { "Emiten_ID": 'BTB', "Lot": 700, "Price": 2900 }, { "Emiten_ID": 'BI', "Lot": 150, "Price": 200 }, { "Emiten_ID": 'AAI', "Lot": 200, "Price": 600 }, ],
    result = [];

myArray.forEach(function (a) {
    if (!this[a.Emiten_ID]) {
        this[a.Emiten_ID] = { Emiten_ID: a.Emiten_ID, Lot: 0, Price: 0 };
        result.push(this[a.Emiten_ID]);
    }
    this[a.Emiten_ID].Lot += a.Lot;
    this[a.Emiten_ID].Price = Math.max(this[a.Emiten_ID].Price, a.Price);
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

ES6 with a closure of `hash` without use of `this`.

```js
var myArray = [{ "Emiten_ID": 'SMBR', "Lot": 500, "Price": 2500 }, { "Emiten_ID": 'SMBR', "Lot": 300, "Price": 2200 }, { "Emiten_ID": 'ELSA', "Lot": 500, "Price": 1000 }, { "Emiten_ID": 'SMBR', "Lot": 100, "Price": 3000 }, { "Emiten_ID": 'BI', "Lot": 300, "Price": 500 }, { "Emiten_ID": 'AAI', "Lot": 200, "Price": 1300 }, { "Emiten_ID": 'BTB', "Lot": 700, "Price": 2900 }, { "Emiten_ID": 'BI', "Lot": 150, "Price": 200 }, { "Emiten_ID": 'AAI', "Lot": 200, "Price": 600 }, ],
    result = [];

myArray.forEach((hash => a => {
    if (!hash[a.Emiten_ID]) {
        hash[a.Emiten_ID] = { Emiten_ID: a.Emiten_ID, Lot: 0, Price: 0 };
        result.push(hash[a.Emiten_ID]);
    }
    hash[a.Emiten_ID].Lot += a.Lot;
    hash[a.Emiten_ID].Price = Math.max(hash[a.Emiten_ID].Price, a.Price);
})(Object.create(null)));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: What does `this` refer to in this answer?

Comment: it refers to thisArg: `Object.create(null)`.

Comment: Hi @NinaScholz. I know you love using the `thisArg` parameter to `forEach` etc. as a sort of free context variable, but based on the comment above I guess it's not only me who finds it a bit counter-intuitive.

Comment: Cool, makes it functionally equivalent to `temp` in my answer.  I learned something new today :-).

Comment: @torazaburo, would a closure fits better?

Answer (score 3):

Using Map class available in ECMAScript 2015 (or polyfill):

```js
var myArray = [{ "Emiten_ID": 'SMBR', "Lot": 500, "Price": 2500 }, { "Emiten_ID": 'SMBR', "Lot": 300, "Price": 2200 }, { "Emiten_ID": 'ELSA', "Lot": 500, "Price": 1000 }, { "Emiten_ID": 'SMBR', "Lot": 100, "Price": 3000 }, { "Emiten_ID": 'BI', "Lot": 300, "Price": 500 }, { "Emiten_ID": 'AAI', "Lot": 200, "Price": 1300 }, { "Emiten_ID": 'BTB', "Lot": 700, "Price": 2900 }, { "Emiten_ID": 'BI', "Lot": 150, "Price": 200 }, { "Emiten_ID": 'AAI', "Lot": 200, "Price": 600 }, ]

var temp = new Map();

for (var item of myArray) {
    var e = temp.get(item.Emiten_ID)
    if (e) {
        e.Lot += item.Lot;
        e.Price = Math.max( e.Price, item.Price );
    } else {
        temp.set( item.Emiten_ID, 
            { Emiten_ID: item.Emiten_ID, Lot:item.Lot, Price:item.Price })
    }
}

var result = Array.from(temp.values());

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I think it's because you're adding the values to the map as properties, rather than entries. You should be doing `map.set`, right?

Comment: Your right @torazaburo, that works.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: The first line in the for loop should read `temp.get`, right?

Comment: I was wondering about that.   Seems to work in node.js without using `temp.get`, but it seems like good style to use the symmetrical approaches.  Updated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [linq.js](http://linqjs.codeplex.com/) library:

```js
var myArray = [
  {"Emiten_ID":'SMBR',"Lot":500,"Price":2500},     
  {"Emiten_ID":'SMBR',"Lot":300,"Price":2200},     
  {"Emiten_ID":'ELSA',"Lot":500,"Price":1000},
  {"Emiten_ID":'SMBR',"Lot":100,"Price":3000},     
  {"Emiten_ID":'BI',"Lot":300,"Price":500},     
  {"Emiten_ID":'AAI',"Lot":200,"Price":1300},
  {"Emiten_ID":'BTB',"Lot":700,"Price":2900},     
  {"Emiten_ID":'BI',"Lot":150,"Price":200},     
  {"Emiten_ID":'AAI',"Lot":200,"Price":600},
];
var answer = Enumerable.From(myArray).GroupBy("x => x.Emiten_ID", "x => {Lot: x.Lot, Price: x.Price}").Select("x => {Emiten_ID:x.Key(), Lot:x.Sum(y=>y.Lot), Price:x.Max(y=>y.Price)}").ToArray();
answer.forEach(x => console.log(x));
```

```html
<script data-require="jquery@3.0.0" data-semver="3.0.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script data-require="linq.js@2.2.0+2" data-semver="2.2.0+2" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/linq.js/2.2.0.2/linq.js"></script>
<script data-require="linq.js@2.2.0+2" data-semver="2.2.0+2" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/linq.js/2.2.0.2/jquery.linq.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

this is long way to this,
hope there is simpler way do this.

```
var myArray = [
  {"Emiten_ID":'SMBR',"Lot":500,"Price":2500},     
  {"Emiten_ID":'SMBR',"Lot":300,"Price":2200},     
  {"Emiten_ID":'ELSA',"Lot":500,"Price":1000},
  {"Emiten_ID":'SMBR',"Lot":100,"Price":3000},     
  {"Emiten_ID":'BI',"Lot":300,"Price":500},     
  {"Emiten_ID":'AAI',"Lot":200,"Price":1300},
  {"Emiten_ID":'BTB',"Lot":700,"Price":2900},     
  {"Emiten_ID":'BI',"Lot":150,"Price":200},     
  {"Emiten_ID":'AAI',"Lot":200,"Price":600},
];

var sortedIds = [];
var Result = [];
function sortArray(){

    for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
        if(myArray.indexOf(myArray[i].Emiten_ID) < 0){
            sortedIds.push(myArray[i].Emiten_ID);
            Result.push({
                "Emiten_ID" : myArray[i].Emiten_ID,
                "Lot"       : sumLot(myArray[i].Emiten_ID),
                "Price"     : maxPrice(myArray[i].Emiten_ID);
            });


        }
    }   

    //out put
    console.log(Result);
}

function sumLot(id){
    var sum = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
        if(myArray[i].Emiten_ID == id){
            sum += myArray[i].lot;
        }
    }   
    return sum;
}

function maxPrice(id){
    var max = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
        if(myArray[i].Price > max){
            max = myArray[i].Price;
        }
    }   
    return max;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var myArray = [
  {"Emiten_ID":'SMBR',"Lot":500,"Price":2500},     
  {"Emiten_ID":'SMBR',"Lot":300,"Price":2200},     
  {"Emiten_ID":'ELSA',"Lot":500,"Price":1000},
  {"Emiten_ID":'SMBR',"Lot":100,"Price":3000},     
  {"Emiten_ID":'BI',"Lot":300,"Price":500},     
  {"Emiten_ID":'AAI',"Lot":200,"Price":1300},
  {"Emiten_ID":'BTB',"Lot":700,"Price":2900},     
  {"Emiten_ID":'BI',"Lot":150,"Price":200},     
  {"Emiten_ID":'AAI',"Lot":200,"Price":600},
];

myArray = myArray.sort(function(a,b){
 if(a.Emiten_ID > b.Emiten_ID)
  return 1;
 else if(a.Emiten_ID < b.Emiten_ID)
  return -1;
 else{
  return a.Price - b.Price;
 }
});

var result = [myArray[0]];

for(var i = 1 ; i < myArray.length ; i ++){
 var obj = myArray[i];
 var res = result[result.length - 1];
 
 if(obj.Emiten_ID == res.Emiten_ID){
  res.Lot += obj.Lot;
  res.Price = Math.max(res.Price,obj.Price);
 }else{
  result.push(obj);
 }

}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution using lodash:

```
_.chain(myArray).groupBy('Emiten_ID').map(emiten => ({
  "Emiten_ID":emiten[0]['Emiten_ID'],
  "Lot": _.sumBy(emiten, 'Lot'),
  "Price": _.maxBy(emiten, 'Price')['Price']
})).value()
```

Answer (score 1):

- Iterate all the `array` elements
- Find the index of `each-element` from new array
- If element does not exist, push it in `array`
- If element exists, sum the value of `Lot` and if value of `Price` is heigher, over-ride the heigher value

```js
var myArray = [{
        "Emiten_ID": 'SMBR',
        "Lot": 500,
        "Price": 2500
    }, {
        "Emiten_ID": 'SMBR',
        "Lot": 300,
        "Price": 2200
    }, {
        "Emiten_ID": 'ELSA',
        "Lot": 500,
        "Price": 1000
    }, {
        "Emiten_ID": 'SMBR',
        "Lot": 100,
        "Price": 3000
    }, {
        "Emiten_ID": 'BI',
        "Lot": 300,
        "Price": 500
    }, {
        "Emiten_ID": 'AAI',
        "Lot": 200,
        "Price": 1300
    }, {
        "Emiten_ID": 'BTB',
        "Lot": 700,
        "Price": 2900
    }, {
        "Emiten_ID": 'BI',
        "Lot": 150,
        "Price": 200
    }, {
        "Emiten_ID": 'AAI',
        "Lot": 200,
        "Price": 600
    }];
    var newArr = [];

    myArray.forEach(function (el) {
        var findIndex = newArr.findIndex(function (item) {
            return item.Emiten_ID === el.Emiten_ID;
        });
        if (findIndex === -1) {
            newArr.push(el);
        } else if (el.Price > newArr[findIndex].Price) {
            newArr[findIndex].Price = el.Price;
            newArr[findIndex].Lot += el.Lot;
        } else {
            newArr[findIndex].Lot += el.Lot;
        }
    });
    console.log(JSON.stringify(newArr, null, 4));
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to decompose this. We'll start by writing a generic utility function which we will call `combine`, which combines properties on objects using a function specified for each property in a hash called `combiners`:

```
function combine(array, combiners) {
  const result = {};
  for (prop of Object.keys(combiners)) {
    result[prop] = combiners[prop](...array.map(elt => elt[prop]));
  }
  return result;
}
```

Example of using this:

```
combine(
  [{a: 1, b: 10}, {a: 42, b: 80}],
  {a: sum, b: Math.max}
)
```

which will result in

```
{a: 43, b: 80}
```

Of course, to make this work, we'll have to define `sum`:

```
function sum(...vals) { return vals.reduce(add); }
```

where `add` is just

```
function add(a, b) { return a + b; }
```

Next, we will group the input by the `Emiten_ID` property. You could use Underscore's `_.groupBy` for this, or write your own (see below).

```
const groups = _.groupBy(myArray, 'Emiten_ID`);
```

This will result in something looking like

```
{ SMBR: [
    { Emiten_ID: 'SMBR', "Lot": 500, "Price": 2500},     
    { Emiten_ID: 'SMBR', "Lot": 300, "Price": 2200}
  ],
  ELSA: [
  ]
}
```

After doing this prep work, it is pretty easy to get the result, by just mapping each value in `groups` using our `combine` utility:

```
const Result = Object.keys(groups).map(key =>
  combine(
    groups[key], 
    {
      Emiten_ID: identity, 
      Lot: sum, 
      Price: Math.max}));
```

where `identity` is just

```
function identity(id) { return id; }
```

If you'd prefer to abstract away the notion inside `combine` of mapping object properties, you could use some utility from Underscore again, or write it yourself:

```
function mapObject(obj, fn) {
  const result = {};

  for (prop of obj) result[prop] = fn(obj[prop], prop);
  return result;
}
```

Example of using this:

```
mapObject({a: 2, b: 3}, x => x * x)
// yields {a: 4, b: 9}
```

Now you can write `combine` a bit more simply, as

```
function combine(array, combiners) {
  return mapObject(combiners, function(combiner, prop) {
    return combiner(...array.map(elt => elt[prop]));
  };
}
```

In case you don't want to use Underscore's `_.groupBy`, here's a home grown version:

```
function groupBy(array, prop) {
  var result = {};
  array.forEach(elt => (result[elt[prop]] = result[elt[prop]] || []).push(elt));
  return result;
}
```

Comment: `const Result = Object.keys(groups).map(key => return combine(` you could skip `return`.